# Why does Google AutoML Sample Python Code Not Run?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

The sample Google AutoML prediction python code causes an error on execution. Recommended execution is "python predict.py YOUR_LOCAL_IMAGE_FILE YOUR_PROJECT_ID YOUR_MODEL_ID" Error is:

File "predict.py", line 25
    print get_prediction(content, project_id,  model_id)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(Thanks in advance)

## Google sample code

```
import sys

from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1
from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1.proto import service_pb2


def get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id):
  prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()

  name = 'projects/{}/locations/us-central1/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_id)
  payload = {'image': {'image_bytes': content }}
  params = {}
  request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)
  return request  # waits till request is returned

if __name__ == '__main__':
  file_path = sys.argv[1]
  project_id = sys.argv[2]
  model_id = sys.argv[3]

  with open(file_path, 'rb') as ff:
    content = ff.read()

  print get_prediction(content, project_id,  model_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

last line of the code `print...` should not be in line indent.

```
import sys

from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1
from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1.proto import service_pb2


def get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id):
  prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()

  name = 'projects/{}/locations/us-central1/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_id)
  payload = {'image': {'image_bytes': content }}
  params = {}
  request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)
  return request  # waits till request is returned

if __name__ == '__main__':
  file_path = sys.argv[1]
  project_id = sys.argv[2]
  model_id = sys.argv[3]

  with open(file_path, 'rb') as ff:
    content = ff.read()

print get_prediction(content, project_id,  model_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

print (get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id))

```
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1
from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1.proto import service_pb2


# 'content' is base-64-encoded image data.
def get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id):
    prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()

    name = 'projects/{}/locations/us-central1/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_id)
    payload = {'image': {'image_bytes': content }}
    params = {}
    request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)
    return request  # waits till request is returned

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    project_id = sys.argv[2]
    model_id = sys.argv[3]

with open(file_path, 'rb') as ff:
    content = ff.read()

print (get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Answers are better when they have an explanation to go with the code that you post _ Please take a moment to visit SO Help Center and specifically the section on 'Answering' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer